# How to open iframe link in new tab or window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tabs, hyperlink

I am using some iframe tags in my html page as  shown below:

```
   <TABLE border="0" width="900">
    <tr valign="top">
    <td width="300" ALIGN=center>
                  <iframe src='http://www.apple.com/in/'  frameborder = 0, height=250, width = 300  > </iframe><br>

    </div>
       </td>

    <td width="300" ALIGN=center>
            <div class="item_list">
            <iframe src = 'http://www.flipkart.com/affiliate/displayWidget?affrid=WRID-137232779171598318'  frameborder = 0, height=250, width = 300 base target="_blank"  > </iframe></a><br>
            </div>
      </td>
      <td width="300" ALIGN=center>
            <div class="item_list">
            <iframe src = 'http://www.flipkart.com/affiliate/displayWidget?affrid=WRID-  137232785207215857' frameborder = 0, height=250, width = 300 > </iframe>
      <br></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
     </TABLE>
```

Now what i need , is to open the link which is inside in iframe to new tab or window. I have used below script regarding this, but no luck.

```
   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

   function goNewWin() {

    //***Get what is below onto one line***

    window.open("backbuttonnewpage.html",'TheNewpop','toolbar=1,
   location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,
    scrollbars=1,resizable=1'); 

   //***Get what is above onto one line*** 

   self.close()

      }

   </SCRIPT>
```

can anyone suggest me any solution for this?

Comment: try parent.window.open("backbuttonnewpage.html",'TheNewpop','toolbar=1,
   location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,
    scrollbars=1,resizable=1');

Comment: @Iv0gun9 it's not working any other alternative

Comment: Check [this][1] solution, hope it helps


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583792/make-links-inside-an-iframe-open-in-a-new-window

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to just open a new page in a new tab. If so, here is the code you need:

```
<a href="WebAdress.netdom" target="_blank"><button>Open New Tab</button></a>
```