# Can a Login form (hosted from a different site) shown within an iframe (from different site) open a new window when submitted?

Tags: iframe

We have a webpage that contains an iframe displaying a login form being hosted from a different site.

What we are looking to do is when we enter in the username and password in the login form within the iframe, it will open a new separate window when a user successfully login or submitted the login information. The new window should be the site that is hosting the login information. Please help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Rhee

Answer (score 0):

Check this post for similar issue.

[Make links inside an iframe open in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583792/make-links-inside-an-iframe-open-in-a-new-window)

It is pretty much not allowed to aceess (through javascript) with pages that are inside iframe from the parent page.